# Editor font in LyX

Tags: lyx, editors

The font used in LyX editor is very small for me to read. I want to increase it. Please not that I am not asking how to change the font size in the output. I could not find in the menu. (I am using LyX with MiKTeX in Windows 7)

Comment: This sounds like a question for google. What about: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=23786 ?

Comment: Hold down Ctrl and scroll up in the text area as is for most windows applications?

Comment: Note that you can also control the size of different layouts. For example, you could make _only_ ERT text large, etc. To learn how to have this fine level of customization though you would need to read the manuals. See Help > Customization

Answer (score 7):

Menu <kbd>Tools</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Look & Feel</kbd> > <kbd>Screen Fonts</kbd>

[image: MWE]

As commented, also with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse wheel you can increase the font size at any time.