# LyX doesn't show boldface letters in MacOS Mojave

Tags: lyx, macos

This is a bit strange but LyX installed on my system which has now MacOS Mojave has stopped showing boldface letters. It was working perfectly on MacOS Sierra. Initially, I had LyX 2.3.0, I tried upgrading it to 2.3.1 but that didn't work either. I tried searching it on Google but found no relevant information. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is the bold text also missing when you view the PDF, or only in the editor?

Comment: Its only in the editor.

Comment: In that case there might be a problem with the settings for the editor font, you could try to select another font to test if that is indeed the problem (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254943/editor-font-in-lyx).

Comment: Thank you. But this isn't working.

Comment: Ditto, I second this problem!

Comment: @wolfsatthedoor Resolved:27 Sep '18 9:55 AM try download 2.32 https://www.lyx.org/Download

Answer (score 7):

Attempting to answer the question of "Does anyone have any idea of what's going on?", this is a bug that is specific to using LyX with Mojave, and is tracked at https://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/11271. This does not appear to be a LyX bug. You can follow an upstream Qt bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69955.

As for when LyX could include a fix, first Qt would need to provide a fix in a new version of Qt. Then, LyX would need to use at least that version of Qt to build a new LyX version. If you are interested in building both Qt and then LyX, write to lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org and we can try to help you. If you don't have experience with this type of thing, it might take a while to get set up.